# Cannot activate virtualenv

Tags: 16.04, python

I have I have installed python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
me@server:~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv/bin$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 May  4 11:45 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 me me 4096 May  4 11:45 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2172 May  4 11:45 activate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 1288 May  4 11:45 activate.csh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2452 May  4 11:45 activate.fish
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    9 May  4 11:45 python -> python3.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    9 May  4 11:45 python3 -> python3.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me   37 May  4 11:45 python3.6 -> /home/me/miniconda3/bin/python3.6*
me@server:~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv/bin$ cd ..
me@server:~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv$ source /bin/activate
-bash: /bin/activate: No such file or directory
me@server:~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv/bin$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 May  4 11:45 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 me me 4096 May  4 11:45 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2172 May  4 11:45 activate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 1288 May  4 11:45 activate.csh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2452 May  4 11:45 activate.fish
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    9 May  4 11:45 python -> python3.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    9 May  4 11:45 python3 -> python3.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me   37 May  4 11:45 python3.6 -> /home/me/miniconda3/bin/python3.6*

me@server:~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv/bin$ cd ..
me@server:~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv$ source /bin/activate
-bash: /bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

I can't activate the virtualenv. I'm thinking this is likely permission based. Is this correct? If so , is there a way to set the permissions when making the virtualenv so it will just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your output you're sourcing `/bin/activate` not `~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv/bin/activate` where the file actually lives.

If you're in the `~/sites/mysite.org/virtualenv/` directory you could run it like:

`source ./bin/activate`
or 
`source bin/activate`

Notice though, that in my examples I don't start with `/` because that would mean starting at the root of the Linux filesystem.